# How to declare NOT VALID PostgreSQL constraints with SQLAlchemy and alembic?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'd like to create a PostgreSQL `CHECK` constraint that is marked as `NOT VALID`, yet I don't see a way to create such constraint in alembic or declare it using SQLAlchemy.

It looks like SQLAlchemy added support for introspection of `NOT VALID` constraints, but not the other way around: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/3980a9a455d08c5073cabc3c2b77de46fa36d7b4 .

Is there a way to do that? Or is the feature just missing and I need to manually write the SQL statements with alembic?

Comment: At present in Alembic "Some free-standing constraint additions and removals may not be supported, including PRIMARY KEY, EXCLUDE, CHECK", so I think you need to write the Alembic script yourself.

Comment: I was able to get SQLAlchemy to emit the DDL at table creation time, but even then Alembic does not include the 'NOT VALID' option (as does Postgres, in a `CREATE TABLE`). When I added the constraint code after the table had been created Alembic did not create a migration for it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks, I was under the same impression. I opened a PR to have `NOT VALID` natively supported in SQLAlchemy: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/pull/7601 . This should also work seamlessly with alembic. TBH, I'm very surprised nobody did that before: it's a quite old and useful feature of postgres, so I really thought I was missing something. I'm even more surprised nobody raised this use case in public before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for declaring `NOT VALID` constraints in PostgreSQL dialect was added in [SQLAlchemy 1.4.32](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html#change-7be0ff44490f0cf83347854a3ca59a82). Such constraint can be declared by setting `postgresql_not_valid` dialect option to `True`:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa


sa.CheckConstraint(
    "lastname IS NOT NULL",
    postgresql_not_valid=True,  # ⬅
)
sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(
    ["head_teacher_id"],
    ["teachers.id"],
    postgresql_not_valid=True,  # ⬅
)
```

Alembic's [`create_check_constraint`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_check_constraint) and [`create_foreign_key`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_foreign_key) functions will forward any dialect option to SQLAlchemy, therefore creating a migration with such constraint is pretty straightforward:

```py
from alembic import op


def upgrade():
    op.create_check_constraint(
        "ck_lastname_not_null",
        "students",
        "lastname IS NOT NULL",
        postgresql_not_valid=True,  # ⬅
    )
    op.create_foreign_key(
        "fk_head_teacher",
        "students",
        "teachers",
        ["head_teacher_id"],
        ["id"],
        postgresql_not_valid=True,  # ⬅
    )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_constraint("ck_lastname_not_null", "students")
    op.drop_constraint("fk_head_teacher", "students")
```

See also [PostgreSQL constraint options](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-constraint-options) documentation.